# rspec `its` syntax with dynamic conditions

Tags: ruby, scope, rspec2

I've been really loving using `contexts`, `subjects` and `its` with rspec to really clean up my test code.  Typical example:

```
context "as a user" do
  subject{ Factory :user }

  its(:name){ should == "Bob" }
end
```

What I can't figure out though is how I could make this condition dynamic (ie. based on other objects).  `its` appears to instance eval the attribute within the block so I lose access to everything around it.  I'd love to do something like:

```
its(:name){ should == subject.contact.name }
```

But I can't see any way of achieving this.  Does anyone know if there is some a method proxied through to this instance eval that gives access to the origin object? Or if there's any other way I can use methods outside the scope of the instance of the attribute that I'm checking?

#### additional info

It seems as if `subject` within the `its` block gets changed to the actual attribute (`name` in this case)

Interestingly, I have access to any of my `let` methods, but again, I don't have access to my original `subject` in question.

Comment: Could you rephrase your question? It sounds like you're onto something interesting, but your example is bad, because you're trying to test inner implementation instead of outer behaviour.

Comment: my question has nothing to do with this particular implementation.  Rather, I want to reference my `user` set as subject within my `its` block, but it seems after some exploration that subject within `its` now becomes the attribute (`name` in this case)

Comment: Note that this is probably not a great idea, because it won't give you a meaningful description in your spec report: you'll see `should == "Bob"` in the report, whereas what you really want to see is `should equal the contact's name` -- and there's no way to do that with `its` syntax that I'm aware of. I love `its`, but I only use it to match constants because of this limitation.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You are almost answering yourself, use a `let` assignment before you set the subject. Then you can reference it everywhere:

```
context "as a user" do
  let(:user) { Factory(:user) }
  subject { user }
  its(:name) { should == user.contact.name }
end
```

I'm a `context`, `subject`, `its` lover too !

Comment: ya I guess that makes sense.  Just wasn't sure if there was a better way.

Comment: rspec now supports `subject(:user) {user}`.. so the `let(:user)..` declaration can be dropped

Comment: @David Sorry, but editing on SO is actually encouraged. http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/edit

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if there's a way to do exactly what you're asking for since the "subject" within the block becomes the return value of `User#name`.

Instead, I've used the `let` method along with the following spec style to write this kind of test:

```ruby
describe User do

  describe '#name' do
    let(:contact) { Factory(:contact, name: 'Bob') }
    let(:user) { Factory(:user, contact: contact) }

    subject { user.name }

    it { should == 'Bob' }
  end

end
```

This of course makes some assumptions about what your contact represents (here it's an association or similar). You may also choose to stub the return value of `User#contact` instead of relying on FactoryGirl to set up a "real" association.

Regardless of the choices you make on those fronts, this strategy has worked well for me. I find it allows me to be more concise about what is under test, while preserving info (for other devs & future self) about where the expected return value is coming from.

Comment: thanks, I think moreso then to answer my question, something like: `it{ should == contact.name }` should work since I appear to have access to `contact` in this scope

Comment: Yes, that should work, but in my opinion you should be explicit about the return value ... eg: verify that it really is `'Bob'` and don't rely on `Contact#name` returning the correct value in your assertion. Not a big deal in this case, but consider the possibility that both of those methods inadvertently return `nil` - the test would pass even though the return values are incorrect.

Answer (score -5):

You can just set an instance variable within the subject block:

```
context 'as a user' do
  subject { @user = FactoryGirl.create(:user) }

  its(:name) { should == @user.name }
end
```

Comment: let() is preferable to instance variables.